# ErrorException in 2b026073a4c3afa6c3599efffe5361a356c89d88.php line 63: Trying to get property of non-object (View: \index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel

model user

```
protected $table = "users";
protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password' ];


protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

public function solicitud(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\solicitud');        
}
```

Model tiposolicitud

```
      protected $table = "tiposolicitud";
protected $fillable = ['nombre'];


public function solicitud(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\solicitud');        
}
```

Model solicitud ( principal )

```
  protected $table = "solicitud";
  protected $fillable = [..extract...   'tiposolicitud_id','users_id'....];


  public function tiposolicitud(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\tiposolicitud');
}

      public function User(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Controller ( extract)

```
 use App\solicitud as VarModel;
 use App\User;
 use App\tiposolicitud ;
 ...
 public function index()
{

    $var1 = VarModel::all();
    return view('private.solicitud.index',compact('var1'));
}
```

index.php

```
  @foreach ($var1 as $var)
   <tr>
       <td>{{$var->id}}</td>               // OK
       <td>{{$var->user->name}}</td>       //NOT OK
       <td>{{$var->tiposolicitud}}</td>    // OK
```

> Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\wamp64\www\issdgr\resources\views\private\solicitud\index.blade.php)

I have problem with app / user

I have persisted the id of the user but I can not find the name ..

HELP!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The error is on your `blade view` with the following statement:

```
$var->id
```

I think its a multi-dimension `Std Class Object`. So before iterating, put a `print_r()` to check the content of it.

And one more thing, laravel maintain `cache` of all views inside

```
your_project/storage/framework/views
```

with name like `2b026073a4c3afa6c3599efffe5361a356c89d88.php` that's why it is showing error here.